# kubectl wait until pod is gone (Terminating)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I know I can use `kubectl wait` to check if a pod is `Ready` but is there an easy way to check whether the pod is gone or in `Terminating` state? I'm running some tests and I only want to continue when the pod (or the namespace for that matter) is completely gone.

Also a timeout option would come in handy.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually part of the wait command.

```
kubectl wait --for=delete pod/busybox1 --timeout=60s
```

You can check with `kubectl wait --help` to see this example and some more. For example

> --for='': The condition to wait on: [delete|condition=condition-  name|jsonpath='{JSONPath expression}'=JSONPath
> Condition]. The default status value of condition-name is true, you > can set false with condition=condition-name=false.

Comment: It doesn't work for me: `k run pru --image alpine -- sleep 2;k wait --for=delete pod/pru --timeout=5s`, as I reach the timeout.

Comment: @david.perez, your timeout is probably too short. By the time Kubernetes has pulled the image and started container and so on, 5 seconds are already passed.

Comment: I think I was missing the `restartPolicy: Never`

Comment: @david.perez, good point. Kubernetes would just restart the container over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

If you execute `kubectl delete po' <pod name>`, the command will automatically wait until the pod is deleted. This is thanks to the `finalizers` feature that keeps the resource (the Pod in this case) from being deleted until the dependent resources (the containers of the pod for example) are cleaned up by the kubelet.

Comment: In the current kubectl version, you need to do `kubectl delete --wait=true ..` to get this behavior.  You may also want to look at the `--cascade` option.